# Opening $MFT file causes Access denied even if run as administrator

Tags: c, windows, winapi, ntfs

I am trying to delete a file record from MFT which I am doing successfully if I open the raw partition and reaching to required file record by parsing MFT file. Problem with this approach  is that I have to lock the volume first so that I can write zeros on any MFT file record and if some other process is holding the volume lock (which is very very probable), write to raw volume fails due Windows OS restrictions.

The other approach that I think of is opening "$MFT" as file and then read and write to it. By this way I THINK I wont have to lock the volume. But when I try to open $MFT file through createfile winapi function, "Access denied" error is raised even if I run my program as an Administrator?

My question is that how can I open $MFT system file to write and read? Does windows OS allows system files to read and write in normal way? If not, what else can I do?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why on earth are you doing this?

Comment: errr.....for file wiping/shredding application so that the file can not recovered....?

Comment: you can do *that* by opening the file, writing random data, & flushing.  Repeat several times, and then delete.  No need to bypass the file system.

Comment: I am doing just that except after deleting the file, I need to delete its entry from Master File table as well to remove all traces of that file.

Comment: You have to lock the volume.  Otherwise you're trying to access the MFT file at the same time as the file system driver is, which (a) causes a sharing conflict, resulting in access denied; and (b) if you didn't get a sharing conflict, would sooner or later result in corrupting the MFT.  What happens, for example, if NTFS writes a change to the record just after you've zeroed it?  Or if you zero out a record that NTFS has just reused for a different file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$MFT isn't accessible from user-mode programs.  (Thank god.)  It's maintained by the NTFS driver, and the NTFS driver alone knows how to keep it up to date.

For your planned implementation, I'd suggest either using the file system directly, or implement a [file system filter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  There's a [tutorial on writing a file system filter driver](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43586/File-System-Filter-Driver-Tutorial), and some [pointers on detecting deletions](http://www.osronline.com/showThread.cfm?link=97311).  (As always, there are some tricky bits...)

Comment: Ok! I am starting to read about File System filter driver. I want to ask that would my filter driver be able to tell file system driver to delete mft record for the file?

Comment: @JewelThief - which file system driver are you referring to?  Your driver, or NTFS?

Comment: @JewelThief - By the way, are you aware of the [NTFS Change Journal](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0999/journal/journal.aspx)?  It keeps track of all file operations.  I'm not entirely sure this is editable; your secure deletion program will still leave some traces.

Comment: Yes I am aware of NTFS change journal. Lets see I can remove traces of file from there as well and Yes I am talking about NTFS driver.

Comment: Ok I have implemented my program by writing random data on file in write through mode using winapi and I rename the file with random name as well and set its size to zero before deleting it. In initial testing, Recovery softwares dont recover original data but they do recover random file name that I had set (which I expect them to do). Is there any way that I set "null" file name while working in user space?

Answer (score 6):

Just in case someone comes here looking to open `$MFT` for the one legitimate purpose, the [`FSCTL_MOVE_FILE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364577(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364572(v=vs.85).aspx) [`DeviceIoControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx), you need to specify [`FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258116(v=vs.85).aspx) in the second parameter to [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) when opening special streams like [`C:\$MFT::$DATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363911(v=vs.85).aspx)

Opening `$MFT` only lets you refer to the special file when performing `DeviceIoControl` requests, it does not open it for reading and writing like a normal file.

If you really want to read the MFT contents, when you need to get a list of every file on a volume very quickly, see [`FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364563(v=vs.85).aspx), it returns structures like [`USN_RECORD_V2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365722(v=vs.85).aspx), which are essentially MFT records.