# Access denied when ReadFile in $MFT

Tags: windows, assembly, ntfs

I want read MFT table with Windows API, but ReadFile API retrns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. I already run as admin. Here is my code:

```
invoke CreateFileA,addr MFT,FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES,FILE_SHARE_READ,0,3,FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS or FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,0
invoke ReadFile,eax,ADDR buf1,512,AddR readed,0
ret
```

Why ReadFile returns access denied error?

Comment: there's no `invoke` instruction in x86 assembly. Probably you want .NET?

Comment: THERE IS INVOKE on MASM x86 assembly. Don't say what you don't have knowledge!

Comment: hey you're the one that's being wrong here. You didn't tag the correct necessary tags and `invoke` is **not an x86 instruction** in any sense, go looking at the Intel manual. It's an [MASM-specific directive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/73407/using-proto-and-invoke-to-call-a-c-function-from-masm)

Comment: I already said that INVOKE is a MASM directive but you misunderstood me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening $MFT file causes Access denied even if run as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499257/opening-mft-file-causes-access-denied-even-if-run-as-administrator)

Answer (score 0):

You have opened the file with **FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES**, when **ReadFile** needs at least **FILE_READ_DATA**. Maybe try **FILE_GENERIC_READ** in **CreateFile**.

Cheers,
Gabriel